# Is it worthwhile to offer a "recover your status" functionality for a paid version in phone app?

Tags: user-behavior, android

I'm thinking about offering this functionality for the paid version of an app, I think it would take around to 80 hours to achieve the development of such functionality.

To better clarify what the functionality is about, it would allow an user to uninstall its app, be it because he has got tired from it, it fails for whatever reason and the user wants to reinstall it, the user needs to make space in his phone for a certain temporal app and it needs my app to make enough space for that temporal app.

It's to notice that in my app, you may lose several weeks of app use if you decide to uninstall it, so it's not that bad a functionality, but even then, I think cases like the previous ones are not common enough to compensate for the effort of developing such functionality.

Do you think that functionality is worthwhile to develop or do you think that it wouldn't compensate?

Comment: I think it really depends on how valuable it is to the users. Difficult for use to answer that without knowing more.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to give a precise answer in hours against the value of your time, but in a generic sense what you seem to be describing is a way to "recover/undo" an action.

Whilst typically such functionality is isolated within and app, you seem to be describing a function which sits outside of your app.

Some approaches you could consider:

1. A clear warning to the user that uninstalling will remove their data and it cannot be recovered
2. Allowing the user to export and import their data manually (perhaps they are prompted when about to uninstall)
3. Saving the data outside of the app itself (such as to an account online)

Option 1 is your lowest effort solution, but Option 3 is perhaps the best experience, this way the user's data is not tied to your app directly and would be more resilient to cases such as upgrading versions or the user needing to use the app on a different device (be it another phone, or perhaps desktop etc).